# Automating Acrobat & PDF Portfolios

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to automate the creation PDF Portfolios in Acrobat 9? Such as, command line switches or external applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  If you want to try your and at Java programming, you could probably create such a program using [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/).  There is an iText based [example](http://www.lowagie.com/itextwiki/doku.php/collections:kubrick) available.